# adding a background image with url. but the image tag doesn't get higlight

Tags: reactjs

[Check the ScreenShot PLease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oy8d.png)**[Why isn't the 'url(${image})' be like the same as video**.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core'
import './Story.css'

const Story = ( {image, profileSrc, title}) => {
    return (
        <div style= {{  backgroundImage: 'url(${image})' }} 
className='story'> 
        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Story
```

Comment: hey, what is the exact problem again?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using normal '' you should use template literals.
Replace the '' with backticks .

```
{{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your process is right but there is a syntax error. You should rewrite your code like this below. If you want to use the variable inside the object you should use ` symbol not ' this. If you can't find the symbol just copy my code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core'
import './Story.css'

const Story = ( {image, profileSrc, title}) => {
    return (
        <div style= {{  backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }} 
className='story'> 
        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Story
```